# How to Use RenderScript's Allocation Surface with MediaCodec?

Tags: android, video-processing, android-mediacodec, renderscript

I am trying to build sample app. for Editing Videos. So, I am using RenderScript to apply effects on frame buffer. There is 1 approach which works with byte buffer. There is another approach where you can give Decoder a surface (which is associated with RenderScript Input Allocation object), and then you can apply render script pipeline to edit the frame data and finally with Allocation's Output object redirect the output to another surface (probably a surface view).

This Surface approach seems to work, But the final output which I am getting is distorted.
Any Help is appreciated.

```
mDecoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);

here surface = mAllocationYUV.getSurface();
```

[Distorted Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg1WA.png)